# CUDA error device-side assert error with Torchvision

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I've had a problem with Pytorch and CUDA which seems pretty common, where I get "RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered" when building a neural network with CUDA because the output of the model is not compatible with labels for calculating loss. I think this was caused because the output of the model had size [n, 1] instead of [n] where n is the batch size.

Using my own architecture, I could fix this by using .squeeze() in the forward pass function, to get the output to size [n]. Now I am using a pretrained ResNet model from torchvision, I haven't been able to achieve the same thing. I've tried defining my own module for the final layers but it hasn't worked:

```
class final_layers(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(final_layers, self).__init__()
        self.layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(512, 1),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.layers(x)
        return x.squeeze()

model = models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
model.fc = final_layers()
optimizer = Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.0003)
criterion = BCELoss()
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    model = model.cuda()
    criterion = criterion.cuda()
```

This model works fine in Colab with CPU but with GPU I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: This error usually means the tensor shape is incorrect. Which mean it's not suppose to work even in CPU. Did you run it until the end with CPU?

Comment: Hey, yes that is what I thought, which is strange. I didn't run through all my data because it would take forever on CPU, but I did run through multiple batches so it should have calculated loss etc which was the problem before I added the final_layers module

Comment: You can try run without shuffle and see which index it error. Maybe the last batch?

Comment: Then in CPU skip everything until that.

Comment: But after I read evrything again. I think `squeeze` is incorrect choise. Squeezing the tensor will remove any 1 length dimention and usually a bad idea since `batch` can be 1 too. More importantly `BCELoss` should be able to use any input size as long as label and target are the same size. So you should resize the target instead.

Comment: Ah ok I will try that, thanks! I think BCELoss is having a problem with the shape of outputs being [n, 1] instead of [n] - is there a way to fix this without squeeze?

Comment: I think the problem is actually the `y_true` you have has the shape of `[n]` while the `y_pred` from the model gives you `[n, 1]`.

Comment: If you want to reshape a tensor from `[n, 1]` to `[n]`, the most bug proof way is `x.view(-1)`.

Comment: You can also reshape the `y_true` from `[n]` to `[n, 1]` as well in similar manner, like `y.view(-1, 1)`

Comment: Ah that's perfect, thanks! I will use x.view(-1). Now I have restarted the runtime it works fine